# Why is TieredMergePolicy is better than others?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm Studying ElasticSearch and Apache Lucene.

Lately, I found that Apache Lucene has a few Merge Policy but ElasticSearch uses TieredMergePolicy instead of other merge policy such as LogMergePolicy and LogByteSizeMergePolicy.

So I've been searching for information about TieredMergePolicy. I found the algorithm but I couldn't see why TieredMergePolicy is better than others(I mean in general case, not special case)

why is it important to pick similar size segments when segment merging and how it affect the overall performance?

please help me.

Comment: @Halim_Kim If my answer answers your question please remember to accept it by clicking the check box next to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [Chinese post](http://codepub.cn/2016/10/09/Lucene-sets-a-single-index-file-size-of-the-performance-test/) on the topic I found the following statement which provides some insight on the benifit of the `TieredMergePolicy` over the `LogByteSizeMergePolicy` which was Lucene's default merge policy prior to `TieredMergePolicy`:

> The difference between `TieredMergePolicy` and `LogByteSizeMergepolicy` is that the former can merge non-adjacent segments, and distinguish the maximum number of segments allowed to merge at one time `setMaxMergeAtOnce(int v)` and the maximum number of segments allowed in a layer `setSegmentsPerTier(double v)`.

For a more expansive explaination of the `TieredMergePolicy` one great source is the comments on [github](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/TieredMergePolicy.java#L31) for the class.  The following information comes from that source and are available under an Apache 2 license:

Merges segments of approximately equal size, subject to an allowed number of segments per tier.
This is similar to `LogByteSizeMergePolicy`, except this merge policy is able to merge
non-adjacent segment, and separates how many segments are merged at once (`setMaxMergeAtOnce`) from how many segments are allowed per tier (`setSegmentsPerTier`).
This merge policy also does not over-merge (i.e. cascade merges).

For normal merging, this policy first computes a "budget" of how many segments are allowed to
  be in the index. If the index is over-budget, then the policy sorts segments by decreasing size
  (pro-rating by percent deletes), and then finds the least-cost merge. Merge cost is measured by a
  combination of the "skew" of the merge (size of largest segment divided by smallest segment),
  total merge size and percent deletes reclaimed, so that merges with lower skew, smaller size and
  those reclaiming more deletes, are favored.

If a merge will produce a segment that's larger than `setMaxMergedSegmentMB`, then the
  policy will merge fewer segments (down to 1 at once, if that one has deletions) to keep the
  segment size under budget.

**NOTE**: this policy freely merges non-adjacent segments; if this is a problem, use `LogMergePolicy`.

**NOTE**: This policy always merges by byte size of the segments, always pro-rates by
  percent deletes

**NOTE** Starting with Lucene 7.5, there are several changes:
 
+ `findForcedMerges` and `findForcedDeletesMerges`) respect the max segment size by default.
 
+ When `findforcedmerges` is called with `maxSegmentCount` other than 1, the resulting index is
  not guaranteed to have <= `maxSegmentCount` segments. Rather it is on a "best effort" basis.
  Specifically the theoretical ideal segment size is calculated and a "fudge factor" of 25% is
  added as the new `maxSegmentSize`, which is respected.
 
+ `findForcedDeletesMerges` will not produce segments greater than `maxSegmentSize`.

Answer (score 0):

TieredMergePolicy first computes the allowed "budget" of how many segments should be in the index, by counting how many steps the "perfect logarithmic staircase" would require given total index size, minimum segment size (floored), mergeAtOnce, and a new configuration maxSegmentsPerTier that lets you set the allowed width (number of segments) of each stair in the staircase. This is nice because it decouples how many segments to merge at a time from how wide the staircase can be.

Comment: i've read that already, but I can't understand. Could you explain it in other way?